Datetime format and time data not matching timestamp format errors in traceback log =
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in \_run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in \_run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/app/fw_daily/refresh_cache.py", line 849, in \<module\>
sys.exit(main())
File "/app/fw_daily/refresh_cache.py", line 817, in main
use_dd=options.use_dd,
File "/app/fw_daily/refresh_cache.py", line 661, in refresh_fw
query_data(refresh_cache, from_dt, to_dt, table_list)
File "/app/fw_daily/refresh_cache.py", line 491, in query_data
query_table(refresh_cache, query_args, table, from_dt, to_dt)
File "/app/fw_daily/refresh_cache.py", line 384, in query_table
last_query_time = get_last_query_time(refresh_cache, last_query_fname)
File "/app/fw_daily/refresh_cache.py", line 217, in get_last_query_time
last_query_time = get_time_from_file(refresh_cache, last_query_fname)
File "/app/fw_daily/refresh_cache.py", line 209, in get_time_from_file
"%Y%m%d",
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/\_strptime.py", line 577, in \_strptime_datetime
tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = \_strptime(data_string, format)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/\_strptime.py", line 359, in \_strptime
(data_string, format))
ValueError: time data  '  ' does not match format '%Y%m%d'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in \_run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in \_run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/app/fw_daily/refresh_cache.py", line 858, in \<module\>
sys.exit(main())
File "/app/fw_daily/refresh_cache.py", line 826, in main
use_dd=options.use_dd,
File "/app/fw_daily/refresh_cache.py", line 670, in refresh_fw
query_data(refresh_cache, from_dt, to_dt, table_list)
File "/app/fw_daily/refresh_cache.py", line 500, in query_data
query_table(refresh_cache, query_args, table, from_dt, to_dt)
File "/app/fw_daily/refresh_cache.py", line 399, in query_table
last_query_time = from_dt if from_dt \> last_query_time else last_query_time
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date

I have an airflow pipeline for 5 device type stats that has failed. Please see the attached image.
Airflow DAG Failure
As a result, I am unable to generate a firmware report that is needed for aggregate device stats. Upon further inspection in the traceback error logs in the query_fw DAG detailed above, I identify that there are two main errors: a datetime and time data format mismatches.
I have tried changing the timestamp format and reran the python scripts but no changes. Unfortunately, I'm kinda stuck as the result is not working as expected. Any advice on potential solutions would be appreciated!
Thank you!

In the first error, the date you are trying to read is a bunch of spaces instead of a properly formatted date. In the second, one of the objects is a date (with only year-month-day) and the other is a datetime( with hours and seconds). they are not comparable (is "9th of july at 3:45" before or after "9th of july"?)

That is all I can say without an example of the input, and of the code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
